# How to perform big numbers mathematic in Android?

Tags: java, android, math, operations

I'm trying to perform this operations on two number but get NumberFormatException : invalid int : "X"
how can i do this?

```
$hash = $orderid * 3;
$hash = $hash + 15;
$hash = $hash . $userid;
$hash = $hash - 120;
$hash = $hash / 5;
$hash = $hash . $userid;
$hash = $hash - 174;
```

suppose order id is 1426518618 and userid is 9965

EDIT : 
this is php code but there is no difference between this and java except (.) thing! this means two number will be add to each other for example x = 22 and y = 33 then x.y mean 2233

this is my code which i get error:

```
    private String getHash(){
    long hash = 0;

    try{
    hash = (Integer.parseInt(mOrderID))*3;
    hash = hash +15;        
    String temp = String.valueOf(hash);
    hash = Integer.parseInt(temp+MyAccountAdapter.mEditItems.getID());
    hash = hash -120;
    hash = hash / 5;
    temp = String.valueOf(hash);
    hash = Integer.parseInt(temp+MyAccountAdapter.mEditItems.getID());
    hash = hash -174;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.valueOf(hash);
}
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: Is that your code? That's not valid Java.

Comment: What is "$hash = $hash . $userid" supposed to return?

Comment: Why is this tagged Android and Java?  Not Java

Comment: @Pshemo Because of the dot operator.

Comment: This looks like PHP code, and the `.` operator would be a concatenation

Comment: @VivinPaliath  just edited my question

Comment: @Binghammer just edited my question

Comment: `hash` is `Long` and you use `Integer.parseInt`? I think you must use `Long.parseLong.` (My English is bad. sharmande dige)

Comment: If a `long` isn't long enough (after you change `Integer.parseInt` to `Long.parseLong`), then consider using a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use long. It's size is 2^64-1..
You can read more Here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html 
You use Integer.parseInt() when you should use Long.parseLong(). Integer is the wrapping class for the primitive int and Long is for the primitive long. Read some more here: way2java.com/java-lang/wrapper-classes

Comment: can you please write the code down here?! cause I'm doing with long but get error , added my code to my answer

Comment: You use Integer.parseInt() when you should use Long.parseLong(). Integer is the wrapping class for the primitive int and Long is for the primitive long. Read some more here: http://way2java.com/java-lang/wrapper-classes/

Comment: May I suggest that you edit that comment into your answer, to make it complete?

Comment: Good suggestion @David Wallace